# Generate id system with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

If possible, I need to write an XSL file that transforms an XML syntax similar to this

```
<media address="1234 A St.">
  <book title="My Book" isbn="1324-1123-1456-1566" />
  <book title="Your Book" isbn="1232-1123-1456-1566" />
</media>
```

into a format like this

```
<library>

    <information>
       <building id="1">
           <address>1234 A St.</address>
       </building>
    </information>

    <medialist>
        <book_definitions>
            <book_definition id="2" />
            <book_definition id="3" />
        </book_definitions>
        <book_metadata>
           <metadata id="4">
               <isbn>1324-1123-1456-1566</isbn>
               <book_definition_id>2</book_definition_id>
           </metadata>
           <metadata id="5">
               <isbn>1232-1123-1456-1566</isbn>
               <book_definition_id>3</book_definition_id>
           </metadata>
        </book_metadata>
        <book_instances>
            <book_instance id="6">
                <book_definition_id>2</book_definition_id>
                <book_metadata_id>4</book_metadata_id>
                <title>My Book</title>
            </book_instance>
            <book_instance id="7">
                <book_definition_id>2</book_definition_id>
                <book_metadata_id>5</book_metadata_id>
                <title>Your Book</title>
            </book_instance>
        </book_instances>
    </medialist>
</library>
```

I realize the target format is a bit convoluted, but I have no control over it.

I have successfully written XSL to transform most of the XML tags correctly using template modes. ie.

```
<xsl:template match="/media/book" mode="definitions">
<xsl:template match="/media/book" mode="metadata">
<xsl:template match="/media/book" mode="instance">
```

However, I have been trying to use <xsl:number> or some other trick to generate the id's correctly with little success.

The target format has two constraints on the ids: every id attribute, reguardless the <element>, name must be unique. The ids, once sorted, must be sequential, but they can appear in any order in the target format i.e. both (1,2,3,4,5) and (5,2,3,1,4) are acceptable but (1,2,4,5,6) is not.

Is there any way to accomplish this via XSL?

Comment: Are you sure you really need the second constraint? It's going to be difficult enough to make your output nodes link to other output nodes that **do not exist in the input** (and one should properly ask why do you need *that*, too).

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I do need the second constraint. However, assuming that I didn't, is there a way to satisfy only the first constraint using XSL?

Comment: There's a way to satisfy the second constraint, too. The real question is how much effort you are willing to put into it. You and the people trying to help you. I, for one, find the task uninteresting, because I cannot see how this would be helpful for anything.  Your title speaks of primary/foreign keys; well, aside from the fact that the books already have a unique and permanent ISBN, it seems clear that Books (what you call book_definitions) is the parent table, and all the other tables should link to it, not to each other in a cascade.

Comment: Perhaps you are right about the title. I have changed it. As for the example XML, I can't post the actual format as it contains proprietary information and I chose to mimic the format using something commonplace. I unfortunately do not have control over the target format and must conform to their unusual standard. Trust that the requirements are as I describe. As for your disinterest, thank you for your comments, but I would greatly appreciate anyone who is willing to help me further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I just noticed that Ian Roberts already explained this approach, I already was about to write an XSLT for this, so I'll post it regardless - following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <library>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </library>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="media">
        <xsl:variable name="current">
            <xsl:number />
        </xsl:variable>
        <information>
            <building>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$current" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <address>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@address" />
                </address>
            </building>
        </information>
        <medialist>
            <book_definitions>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="definition">
                    <xsl:with-param name="current">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$current" />
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </book_definitions>
            <book_metadata>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="metadata">
                    <xsl:with-param name="current">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$current" />
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </book_metadata>
            <book_instances>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="instances">
                    <xsl:with-param name="current">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$current" />
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </book_instances>
        </medialist>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="book" mode="definition">
        <xsl:param name="current" />
        <book_definition id="{(position() + $current)}" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="book" mode="metadata">
        <xsl:param name="current" />
        <metadata id="{(position() + $current + count(parent::media/book))}">
            <isbn>
                <xsl:value-of select="@isbn" />
            </isbn>
            <book_definition_id>
                <xsl:value-of select="position() + $current" />
            </book_definition_id>
        </metadata>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="book" mode="instances">
        <xsl:param name="current" />
        <book_instance id="{(position() + 2*count(parent::media/book) + $current)}">
            <book_definition_id>
                <xsl:value-of select="position() + $current" />
            </book_definition_id>
            <book_metadata_id>
                <xsl:value-of select="position() + $current + count(parent::media/book)" />
            </book_metadata_id>
            <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
            </title>
        </book_instance>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to your input XML generates the output

```
<library>
 <information>
   <building id="1">
     <address>1234 A St.</address>
   </building>
 </information>
 <medialist>
    <book_definitions>
      <book_definition id="2"/>
      <book_definition id="3"/>
    </book_definitions>
    <book_metadata>
      <metadata id="4">
        <isbn>1324-1123-1456-1566</isbn>
        <book_definition_id>2</book_definition_id>
      </metadata>
      <metadata id="5">
        <isbn>1232-1123-1456-1566</isbn>
        <book_definition_id>3</book_definition_id>
      </metadata>
    </book_metadata>
    <book_instances>
      <book_instance id="6">
        <book_definition_id>2</book_definition_id>
        <book_metadata_id>4</book_metadata_id>
        <title>My Book</title>
      </book_instance>
      <book_instance id="7">
        <book_definition_id>3</book_definition_id>
        <book_metadata_id>5</book_metadata_id>
        <title>Your Book</title>
      </book_instance>
    </book_instances>
  </medialist>
</library>
```

As it's not clear if the input XML consists of multiple `media` elements  - e.g. a next building that then should start with the id 8 - I used the number as parameter instead of just adding 1.
Note that this template won't work for a second `media` element - this would just start with 2 as value for `id` - and would have to be adjusted accordingly in case the real input XML contains multiple buildings / `media` elements.
For book definition, the id is the sum of the position of the current book and the value of the parameter `current`:

```
<book_definition id="{(position() + $current)}" />
```

The metadata id is the sum of the position of the current book, all books of the current / parent `media` element and `current`:

```
<metadata id="{(position() + $current + count(parent::media/book))}">
```

And the book instance id, taking into account the previously generated ids for metadata, is the sum of the position of the current book, `current` and all books of the parent `media` element * 2:

```
<book_instance id="{(position() + 2*count(parent::media/book) + $current)}">
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that since (apart from the building), you're always generating one ID per book for each different "kind" of node, you can guarantee unique and sequential ids by generating them according to a formula. If you have N books then you could "decree" that

- the building is always id 1
- the `book_definition` for book m is always `1+m` (so running from 2 up to N+1)
- the metadata for book m is `(N+1)+m`
- the instance is `(2N+1)+m`

If you follow this scheme everywhere you can simply calculate the appropriate cross reference `book_definition_id` etc. with no need for a lookup table.